# EVAL function showing unexpected result if prepend Zero (0)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an unexpected result from the `eval` function.

```js
alert(eval(1 + 033))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I execute `eval(1 + 033)` it's showing the result as `28`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  How can I get it to treat `033` as the number `33` and produce `34` as the result?

Comment: Looks like the correct result to me.

Comment: @kevin: may i send you the screenshot. Its showing 28. I also checked in other machine. Request you share your snippet.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers

Comment: Yes, 28 is what it should be.

Comment: One solution: Don't use `eval` for simple arithmetic. Another solution: Definitely don't use `eval` for any source you don't control.

Comment: It's nothing to do with eval, the result is the same simply doing `alert(1+033);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string containing a number with a leading zero and you want that number to be treated as a decimal (base-10), you can use parseInt providing 10 as the second parameter.

```
parseInt(string, radix);
```

```js
var str = "033";
var x = parseInt(str, 10);
console.log(x + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`033` is the *octal* representation of (decimal) `27`

so `eval(1+033)` is `eval(1+27)` is `eval(28)` is `28`

Comment: Thanks but whats the solution for it?

Comment: @sAcH Take off the leading zero?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: if non technical user types bi-mistakenly 0 before any digit then it will not show result as per their thought. So how we can overcome on this scenario.?

Comment: perhaps a non-technical user should not be editing the source code of your program?

Comment: if the program is built to accept user input at run time, you can treat the input as a string and use any number of ways to parse a number out of a string in JavaScript (just search here on the site)

Comment: what is the input/output requirements of your program? are you using `eval` to parse numbers? if so, you definitely should be doing something differently...

Comment: @sAcH that information should've been included in your question. That makes it so much clearer what you are trying to achieve